# what is the meaning of a question being closed.

Tags: discussion, support

I'd like to know the meaning of a question being closed. I am under the impression that the OP is not allowed to revise the question anymore. Is there anything more than that ?

Comment: Just to emphasize this key point: the exact opposite is true!  The closing of a question is essentially an *invitation* for the OP to revise the question so as to improve it!

Answer (score 11):

That is false. The OP may revise a closed question as many times as they would like. If they feel that after editing it, the question is now appropriate, the OP can flag their own question with a comment to the moderators to ask them to reopen the question. Some more information about closed questions is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question).

Comment: I would suggest that, instead of flagging for Moderators to re-open, **starting a thread on meta** to advocate for re-opening the question. The same way five 3K+ users can close a question, five 3K+ users can vote to re-open.

Comment: See esp. the highest-voted answer **[Closing Questions Considered Harmful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10589#10589)**

Comment: The important part is for the OP to **fix the question** according to the comments left to make it answerable (for "not a real question" closures) and bring it within the scope and interest of the website (for "off topic" and "too localized" questions).

Comment: @Bill: that is not the highest voted answer.... [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583) is (at the moment; I doubt 14 votes came in within the past 2 minutes).

Comment: @Willie Good luck with getting reopen votes via Meta. As I mentioned before, not enough folks visit mete frequently enough compared to the main site. The asymmetry is atrocious.

Comment: @Bill: you can also **comment** on closed questions. And as I mentioned before, a **good thing** when you start a discussion thread about whether a question should be closed/reopened is to **link to the meta discussion in a comment**.

Comment: @Bill: I also call **bunk** on "not enough folks visiting meta". A somewhat unscientific sampling of 20 (every third row of the user listing by reputation) of the ~50 users with open/close powers gives 14 who visited meta within the past 24 hours, 4 within the past week, and 2 outside that period.

Comment: @Wil I suspect the percentage of closed question that were reopened is under 10%, perhaps under 5%. That's not because all the closed questions were poor (indeed, as Matt mentioned recently, many were perfectly fine questions). Rather, it's because reopening is difficult if not impossible.

Comment: @Bill: I, on the other hand, suspect that most of the questions that were closed were **rightly so**, and the ones that should **not** have been just don't have enough people advocating for them. Why don't you try it some time? Find a question that is closed, as you say, improperly, and post a polite comment on meta explaining why you think the question deserves another chance?

Comment: @Wil Your "bunk" or "unscientific sampling" has little bearing on the fact that closed question don't get reopened - which *can* be backed up with hard numbers from database dumps.

Comment: @Bill: my bunk however, is very forceful against your defeatist attitude about my suggestion, which is based on an incorrect assumption that people don't visit meta. I don't disagree with you that the absolute majority of closed questions do not get re-opened, but that has no bearing on the discussion here, does it?

Comment: @Wil Sorry, I don't agree. Moreover, my claims are actually based on facts, not speculations, viz. hard-earned experiences attempting to get questions reopened.

Comment: I do remember a plea to reopen a certain question working here in meta, but I do not have a link to it offhand.

Comment: @Bill: can I see those facts? Haven't your recent attempts to reopen posts (by posting on meta, nonetheless) mostly worked? Are you really going to assume that this community has been **in stasis since before I joined some 6 months ago**? I know we disagree on many things and I'm in no position to force you to try my suggestion, but I plead with you: give it a try, see if it works. If it doesn't, at least you'll have some facts to convince me with.

Comment: @Bill: I'm probably going blind, but it doesn't seem that any of your 25 meta questions involved a reopening plea...

Comment: @Bill: The number of reopened questions alone is really irrelevant. What would be relevant is the ratio of that number over the number of questions that _deserve_ to be reopened.

Comment: @Wil I've already said that I'm open to the suggestion that Meta has changed enough since the old days that reopening may be easier. But that doesn't change the fact that the software model is fundamentally flawed. Hopefully the SE folks will fix these problems with enough constructive feedback. But I'm not holding my breath...

Comment: @Bill: I completely agree with your last three sentences. I'm all ears if you know (or build yourself! I wish you luck with that) a better alternative.

Comment: @J.M.: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/on-the-continued-impolite-closure-of-questions-by-new-users-for-the-wrong-reasons http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/814/closing-of-is-this-proof-of-a1-2-being-either-integer-or-irrational-circular http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/748/please-exercise-more-restraint-before-voting-to-close-discuss-here-first the latter two do support Bill's impression that in the early days of this website discussion of reopening *was* not very successful.

Comment: @Willie: Oh yeah, I remember that third one... what I got out of it was that Bill was answering a question that wasn't exactly the one asked (though his answer there is highly upvoted, and deservedly so).

Comment: @J.M. We'd probably have much richer answers if folks were not so quick to close questions due to technicalities. Often times students do not have the expertise to properly formulate questions. Sometimes the most interesting answers arise due to various panoramic interpretations given by experts. Even at the frontiers of math it is not always clear what the right questions are or how to best formulate them. One can find remarks to this effect by eminent mathematicians as grand theories like class field theory evolved, and even today in contemporary developments (e.g. Langlands program).

Comment: @J.M. For some recent examples, see the very nice answers provided by Matt E. to questions that were closed on MO and suggested to be closed here, e.g. [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34661/about-the-enigma-of-l-function/34698#34698) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34979/new-idea-on-b-s-d-conjecture/34985#34985). If experts are patient enough to answer such questions then why not let them? Those are only two of *many* superb answers to poorly-posed questions. We'd probably have more answers like this if folks weren't so quick to close questions.

Comment: @Bill: Dear Bill, Thank you for your kind words about my answers.  I do think that some questions that appear poorly posed can nevertheless have an essential kernel of significance, which can lead to meaningful answers from an expert.  In particular, I think that sometimes beginners can ask questions which more experienced people are sometimes averse to asking, which get at important mathematical points.   In general, I have a broad view as to what constitutes a reasonable question, and I agree with Bill that questions shouldn't be closed in haste, or without very good reason. ...

Comment: I also agree with @Willie that at this point in the site's development, posts on meta asking to reopen closed questions have a good chance to be successful (if the closed post has any sort of merit as a question).  My feeling (based partly on MO experience) is that once such meta posts become standard, the asymmetry between closing and reopening becomes less pronounced, because people get used to going to meta to check on the status of various questions, and reopen votes become part of the routine of visiting the site.  Regards,